# Create elements in real time

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm working on an App, this is the form I've created:

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="cen" runat="server">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Contacto</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Hora</th>
                    <th >Mensaje</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>                        
                    <td><input name="user[]" id="correo" type="email" placeholder="contacto@correo.com" style="width: 10em;"></td>
                    <td><input name="date[]" id="fecha" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox"}'></td>
                    <td><input id="hora" name="hour[]" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "timebox", "overrideTimeFormat": 12}'></td>
                    <td><textarea id="mensaje" name="mensaje[]" placeholder="Su mensaje Aqui" style="width: 15em; max-width: 15em;"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Enviar" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </form>
```

The user has a button to allow them to create elements, this is the function:

```
$(function () {
$("#btnagre").on("click", function () {

    var $clone = $("#cen").find("tbody").children().eq(0).clone(true);
    $("#cen").find("tbody").append($clone);
    return false;
});
```

I have the following problem: when I create a child this has gives me the information of it's parent, so that if I then try to change the child only the root changes.

Comment: No hablo Espanol. Nor do most of the people here.

Comment: La cuestion es que stackoverflow es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas EN INGLES, por lo tanto no creo que obtengas una respuesta a tu problema... / The situation is that stackoverflow is a Q&A site IN ENGLISH, therefore I doubt you'll get an answer to your problem...

Comment: Which flag do you use to close non-English questions..?

Comment: @AndrewPeacock "not a real question" because it is difficult to tell what is being asked here :O)

Comment: Te puedo ayudar, pero eso no es jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Gracias Omar, te lo voy a agradecer mucho

Comment: Nominating for re-opening, since the question has now been phrased in English, and should now be understandable to the majority of viewers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clear input elements with this before attaching

```
$clone.find(":input").val("");
```

Comment: Thanks that work, but I having other problem, all the information in the new elements go to the root and no to a especific child

Comment: @Josue Francisco Orellana Vega: not sure what you mean with "go to the root and no to a especific child`

Comment: I mean that if you create a new element, if you try to put information in the new element, that information go to the first element and not in the element that you want to modify